# Spring versions 2.0 and 2.3 differences

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm starting Spring-mvc, i have been using  from Stripes for some time.

Are there many important differences between version 2.0 and 2.3(latest)?

I have found some very interesting books but its about 2.0, and before spending some cash for it i wanted to know if the basics would really make a difference.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of Spring is 3.0.5, not 2.3. And yes, the changes in all modules (including the mvc module) or so huge that it doesn't make sense to learn about Spring 2 now.

You would learn about practices that were best practices then but have been deprecated since, like `HibernateTemplate` or XML-Style MVC.

And especially if you come from a Stripes-background you will want to use Spring MVC 2.5 or later, because that is when Spring switched to an annotation based way of defining controllers which is very similar to the way Stripes does it.